# Filtering works in Linux, but now Windows Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In the code, I'm trying to take out all Z-Scores that are not between -3 and 3. In my Linux VM it runs without error, but when I try to run the exact same code in Windows it gives me the error: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

I can't find why I would be getting the error in Windows, but not Linux.

Code:

```
df['Z-Score'] = df['price'] # Make the Column Z-Score and put the
df['Z-Score'] = stats.zscore(df['Z-Score'])
df['Z-Score'] = df['Z-Score'].between(-3,3)
countZ = df['Z-Score'].count()
print(df[['Z-Score', 'price']].head(5))
df['Z-Score'] = df[df['Z-Score']==True]
countZ1 = df['Z-Score'].count()
total=countZ - countZ1
print('Your total outliers were {}'.format(total))
dfCount = df.count()
df.dropna(inplace=True)
dfCount1 = df.count()
print('You dropped {}'.format(dfCount-dfCount1))
df.count()
```

[Linux screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ly6Kr.png)

[Windows screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfUOK.png)

Data:

```
      Z-Score    price
0     True  530000.0
1     True  740500.0
2     True  625000.0
3     True  595000.0
4     True  485000.0
```

Comment: Doesn't run on my Linux box either if it help.  Consistency in an error is better right? :o).  What is the line `df['Z-Score'] = df[df['Z-Score']==True]` doing?  Are you wanting more than one column? Or is it missing df.loc? Not sure what you're trying to do.  Explain it to the duck: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: The line of code is supposed to filter based on booleans. I double-checked my syntax to this article, point 10, https://towardsdatascience.com/filtering-data-frames-in-pandas-b570b1f834b9     I'm wanting to keep it one column and I'm pretty sure I don't need a .loc. I've been talking to the duck about why this isn't working on windows lol.

Comment: It shouldn't work.  Restart the kernel, reboot the machine, it's perhaps got something in the memory making it work differently.  Run `df[df['Z-Score']==True]` on its own and it returns the whole frame (two columns) where the column `Z-Score` is `True` (as the article suggests see "As shown above, we obtain a data frame object containing only the employees with a salary higher than 45000 euros." - the whole frame is returned).  You cannot assign two columns (in your case) to one column hence the error.  Now `df[['Z-Score', 'price']] = df[df['Z-Score']==True]` works but you may not want that.

Comment: I don't understand why you assing it to `df['Z-Score']`. Why not use new variable like `filtered_df = df[df['Z-Score']==True]`. Eventually `df = df[df['Z-Score']==True]`

Comment: @furas the goal was to keep the number of columns I would have to drop later to a minimum. My perception of how to filter booleans was just a little off. Ended up doing the `df = df[df['Z-Score']==True]` and it worked as intended. I appreciate the assistance!